# User Profiles / Router

Tags: meteor, router

I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to view user profiles by traveling to /player/:username. I have the template, now I just need to call Meteor.users to find the user account by the :username that is specified in the URL. I'm using the Router package.

```
'/player/:username': { 
    to: 'user_profile', 
    and: function(){ 
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ username: username }); 
    } 
},
```

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `var user = Meteor.users.findOne({ username: username });` -- then to look up profile properties of the user, you could do `user.profile.foobar`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is helpful. Although, I'm also wondering how to properly use this in my router and add the info into my template. I edited my original question to add the code that I have so far in my router. Thanks

Comment: ReferenceError: username is not defined.

({ <username>: username })

Comment: @NateDavidRivera you're using `:username` in the path, so the `and: function()` should take username as an argument -- `and: function (username)`

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it would be so. Now in my <template name="user_profile"> I have <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>. This should display the username, no? It isn't working. I feel like I should be doing more. I don't know.

Comment: I'd suggest storing the username in a session variable in the routing method, and doing the actual Meteor.users.findOne bit in a template helper. That way, things like "user.username" will actually be available.

Comment: Ok, so I got it working, almost! I've added a session variable `Session.set('selectedUserId', user._id)` and then:

    `Template.user_profile.user = function(){
 if(userId=Session.get('selectedUserId')){
  return Meteor.users.findOne(userId);
 }
    }`
It works until I leave that page. When I return I get an error: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined. Sorry, I don't know how to format in comments, if it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

I would set the Session variable in the route function, and then use that to return the user in a template helper. So:

```
'/player/:username': { 
    to: 'user_profile', 
    and: function(username){ 
        Session.set('currentUsername', username); 
    } 
},
```

And then in the template helper

```
Template.user_profile.helpers({
  currentUser: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne({username: Session.get('currentUsername')});
  }
})
```

And then in your template

```
<template name="user_profile">
{{#with currentUser}}
User name is {{username}}
{{/with}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although, ideally, I would like these profiles to be viewable by anyone. Logged in or not.

Comment: Yes, this will be viewable by anyone. It is not related to whether a user is logged in or not

Comment: Sorry, was jumping to conclusions.

For some reason If I am logged out, the profile will not show. Also, if I travel to a profile that is not my own, while logged in, the profile does not show.

`console.log(Meteor.users.findOne({username: Session.get('currentUsername')}));` returns `undefined` if not logged in or if on another users profile.

Comment: Check a few things. 1. That the other users do in fact have a username attribute. 2. That you have proper publish/subscribe permissions on the users if autopublish is removed. and 3. The router is not filtering urls based on logged in/out state. If you still need help after checking all of those I would update your answer with what you've investigated so that others will be better armed to help

Comment: Thanks @landland, I didn't have pub/sub for the collection. Such a noob mistake :/ It's working well now. Thanks, again.